# Using Jdbc Template with DataSourceUtils.getConnection method

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

I am not sure below is the correct way to manage a db connectivity in a connection pooled environment using Jdbc template with DataSourceUtils.getConnection.

What I have done:

- We are using ***apache dbcp*** for connection pooling.In Spring appconfig configured connection pooling and Jdbc template as shown below

  `<!--  data source for xxxx-->
  <bean id="dbName"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${oracle.driver}" />
      <property name="url" value="${xxxx.oracle.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${xxxx.oracle.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${xxxx.oracle.password}" />
      <property name="minIdle" value="1" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="jdbcTemplateUib" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dbName" />
  </bean>`
- In DAOImpl, inside the method we have to invoke a stored procedure with custom SQL data types. Hence we are required to get *connection* object for the same. We are getting the connection as follows :

  `this.connection = 
  DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());`

  where *DataSourceUtils* is a Spring implementation described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html).

The above configuration is working fine in local but we are bit worried on the following aspects of this program:

- If we access connection in this manner will it override the connection pooling mechanism in appconfig file?
- As per documnetation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-), DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSource dataSource) will reuse existing connection. So I am assuming this will not break any connection created via JdbcTemplate and dbcp objects.
- No need of explicitly releasing this connection since it is managed by the jdbcTemplate.

I am not quite sure on the above mentioned items. Need some expert opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [JdbcTemplate#execute(ConnectionCallback action)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback-) method. That allows you access to the connection while still taking advantage of Spring's resource and exception management features. You just need to implement the `doInConnection` callback method.

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object doInConnection(Connection connection) 
            throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

         // do your processing here

        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring JDBC offers various utilities for calling stored procedures with custom SQL data types:

- [JdbcOperations#call](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#call-org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator-java.util.List-)
- [SimpleJdbcCall](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html)
- [GenericStoredProcedure](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/GenericStoredProcedure.html)
- subclassing [StoredProcedure](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html)